# How do I add an image to a frame in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have the following problem specification:

> Create a (400 x 400) bitmap white (255) image with a black (0) border to simulate a "picture frame". The frame should be 10 units in from the edge of all sides. Save this image as "ImageFrame.bmp".  Now, insert the "Parrot.png" into the "picture frame".  Find the center of the Parrot picture, and the center of the frame and place the Parrot.

I made the picture frame, but I can’t figure out how to add the parrot into the “picture frame.”  Help would be really appreciated! The parrot picture is 200 X 150.

Below is the code I have attempted to solve this problem

```
ImageParrot = imread('Parrot.png','png');

ImageBlank = uint8(zeros(200,150))
ImageBlank = 255 * uint8(ones(400,400))

imshow(ImageBlank)

ImageFrame = ImageBlank
ImageFrame(10:390,10) = 0;
ImageFrame(10,10:390) = 0;
ImageFrame(10:390,390) = 0;
ImageFrame(390,10:390) = 0;

imshow(ImageFrame)

imwrite(ImageFrame,'ImageFrame.bmp')

imshow(ImageParrot)
ImageParrotLarge = imresize(ImageParrot,2)
imshow(ImageParrotLarge)

ImageParrotRotate = imrotate(ImageParrot,90)
ImageParrotRotate = imrotate(ImageParrot,45)
imshow(ImageParrotRotate)

ImageParrotStretched = imagesc(400,400,ImageParrot)


ImageNewParrot = 255 * uint8(ones(400,400));
ImageNewParrot(40:end,40:end) = ImageParrot

imadd(ImageFrame,ImageParrot)
```

Comment: What is the output currently?

Comment: Also can you provide example of the input images like the parrot one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already answered the first two parts to this question:

1. Create a completely white image
2. Have a border of black 10 pixels within around the image

Assuming that the image is **grayscale**, you can insert the image into the centre of the frame like so:

```
% // Get the centre of the picture frame
[rowsFrame, colsFrame] = size(ImageFrame);
picFrameCenRow = rowsFrame / 2;
picFrameCenCol = colsFrame / 2;

% // Get dimensions of parrot image
[rowsParrot, colsParrot] = size(ImageParrot);

% // Place the parrot in the centre
ImageFrame(picFrameCenRow-(rowsParrot/2) : picFrameCenRow+(rowsParrot/2)-1, ...
           picFrameCenCol-(colsParrot/2) : picFrameCenCol+(colsParrot/2)-1) = ImageParrot;
```

This should place your parrot image in the centre of `ImageFrame`, stored in `ImageFrame`.